# SQL Server 2016 Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot

I have one question regarding `sql` (MS SQL 2016) and `pivot` functionality.
First let me explain about the data structure.

Examples of `tbl_Preise`. There are several prices (`Preis`) for each area (`Gebiet_von`, `Gebiet_bis`) in relays (`StaffelNr`). All connected to the same freight (`Fracht_id`). There can be a different number of relays for each freight. All of these relays repeat for each area, so i.e. there is one price for relay `1` in area `1800 - 1899`, but there is another price for relay `1` for area `1900 - 1999`.

This is how the table `tbl_Preise` looks:

```
autoID  Fracht_id   Gebiet_von  Gebiet_bis  Zielland_Nr StaffelNr   Preis   Mindestpreis    Mautkosten
16933   4           1800        1899        4           1           22,6481 0,00            0,00
16934   4           1800        1899        4           2           37,0843 0,00            0,00
16935   4           1800        1899        4           3           54,9713 0,00            0,00
16936   4           1900        1999        4           1           23,4062 0,00            0,00
16937   4           1900        1999        4           2           84,4444 0,00            0,00
```

Now I have another table `tbl_Fracht_Staffeln` where the quantity of the relay is saved.

This table looks like:

```
id  fracht_id   staffelNr   menge
18  4           1           50
19  4           2           100
20  4           3           150
21  4           4           200
```

Now I want to combine these data, which can vary through different number of relays to each freight.
I have done this via this query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(staffelNr) 
                    from tbl_Preise (nolock)
                    where fracht_id = @freightId
                    group by staffelNr
                    order by StaffelNr
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'
            SELECT 
                Bezeichnung, 
                fracht_id, 
                gebiet_von, 
                gebiet_bis, 
                ' + @cols + N' 
            from 
            (
                select 
                    l.Bezeichnung as Bezeichnung, 
                    Zielland_Nr, 
                    tbl_Preise.fracht_id, 
                    gebiet_von, 
                    gebiet_bis, 
                    preis, 
                    tbl_Preise.staffelNr as staffelNr
                from
                    tbl_Preise (nolock)
                left join 
                    [dbo].[vw_Laender] l on tbl_Preise.Zielland_Nr = l.[Nummer] 
                where 
                    tbl_Preise.Fracht_id = ' + cast(@freightId as nvarchar(100)) + ' 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(preis)
                for staffelNr in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p 
            order by
                gebiet_von, gebiet_bis'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

This query gives me this result:

```
Bezeichnung fracht_id   gebiet_von  gebiet_bis      1       2       3       4       5       6
    Germany     4           01800       01899       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
    Germany     4           06400       06499       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
    Germany     4           1800        1899        22,6481 37,0843 54,9713 64,4062 84,4444 94,6546
    Germany     4           20500       20599       17,9088 27,3983 40,8845 46,7485 61,4905 67,835
    Germany     4           21200       21299       17,9088 27,3983 40,8845 46,7485 61,4905 67,835
    Germany     4           21500       21599       17,9088 27,3983 40,8845 46,7485 61,4905 67,835
```

Don't look exactly on the prices and the area codes. I've changed some in my example of `tbl_Preise` to make the relation and sense more clear.
So far so good. But now, as you can see, I have the `staffelNr` (1,2,3,4,...) as Header in my table.

I need there the column `menge` of table `tbl_Fracht_Staffeln` instead.

I tried already some `joins` and other stuff, but all did not work, because I have found no way to connect the `column names` (1,2,3,4...) to the table `tbl_Fracht_Staffeln`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a one-2-one relationship between `fracht_id`,`staffelNr` and  `menge`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understand you correctly. If you would do a join, you would connect it this way `left join tbl_Fracht_Staffeln on tbl_Preise.staffelNr = tbl_Fracht_Staffeln.staffelNr and tbl_Preise.fracht_id = tbl_Fracht_Staffeln.fracht_id`. But the result will be more than one row, due to the different areas.

Comment: Yor `@Cols` variable has this where clause `where fracht_id = @freightId` - can you not include this in the join too?  It's difficult to understand what the columns refer too as they aren't in English

Comment: No, that does not work as far as I can see. because then the results are duplicated (55 rows to 1449 rows). I need the `staffelNr` and replace the header with the quantity column (`menge`) with the corresponding value of  `tbl_Fracht_Staffeln`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to play with column header 2 times -

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) , @freightId as     int , @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @freightId = 4

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(t1.staffelNr) + ' as  ' +      QUOTENAME(t2.menge )
                    from tbl_Preise t1 (nolock)
                    join tbl_Fracht_Staffeln t2(nolock) 
                    on t1.fracht_id = t2.fracht_id  and  t1.staffelNr =         t2.staffelNr 
                    where t1.fracht_id = @freightId
                    group by t1.staffelNr , t2.menge
                    order by t1.StaffelNr
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @cols1 = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(staffelNr) 
                    from tbl_Preise (nolock)
                    where fracht_id = @freightId
                    group by staffelNr
                    order by StaffelNr
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'
            SELECT 

                fracht_id, 
                gebiet_von, 
                gebiet_bis, 
                ' + @cols + N' 
            from 
            (
                select 

                    Zielland_Nr, 
                    tbl_Preise.fracht_id, 
                    gebiet_von, 
                    gebiet_bis, 
                    preis, 
                    tbl_Preise.staffelNr as staffelNr
                from
                    tbl_Preise (nolock)
                              where 
                    tbl_Preise.Fracht_id = ' + cast(@freightId as     nvarchar(100)) + ' 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(preis)
                for staffelNr in (' + @cols1 + N')
            ) p 
            order by
                gebiet_von, gebiet_bis'
print @query
   exec sp_executesql @query;
```