# Join SQL Server tables and add column values as table headers

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 tables in Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Express:

Table Invoices

```
    InvoiceID InvoiceType InvoiceDate InvoiceSeries InvoiceApology
  -----------|-----------|-----------|-------------|--------------
       1       InvType1    1/1/2020    InvSeries1    InvApology1
       2       InvType2    1/2/2020    InvSeries2    InvApology2
```

Table InvoiceDescriptions

```
    InvoiceDescriptionID InvoiceID AccountingCodeID BookTitleID Amount  VatAmount  TotalAmount
    --------------------|---------|----------------|-----------|-------|----------|-------------
             1               1             3             1      100,00     4,00        104,00
             2               2             1             2       50,00     2,00         52,00
```

Table AccountingCodes

```
    AccountingCodeID AccountingCode AccountingCodeDescription
   -----------------|--------------|-------------------------
          1            64.01.0000        AccDescription1  
          2            64.02.0000        AccDescription2   
          3            64.03.0000        AccDescription3
```

Table BookTitles

```
    BookTitleID  BookTitle
   ------------|------------
         1       BookTitle1
         2       BookTitle2
```

What i am trying to achieve without success is to make a query to show me a table like the one below

Result Table(not create the actual table, only to show it with the query and the BookTitles are going to be more day by day and need to be updated dynamically)

```
    InvoiceID  InvoiceDate InvoiceNumber InvoiceApology TotalAmount  BookTitle1 BookTitle2
   ----------|------------|------------ |--------------|------------|----------|----------
        1      1/1/2020         1         InvApology1      104,00      100,00
        2      1/2/2020         2         InvApology2       52,00                  50,00
```

Comment: Seems like you're going to need to implement (multiple) dynamic pivots here. This seems like you're overly complicating the issue, if I am honest.

Comment: This is absolutely something you should do in your presentation layer (Be it SSRS, Power BI, Excel, whatever) rather than the SQL itself

Comment: you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336909/sql-server-2016-pivot/48341499#48341499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution after many tries with this block of code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempAccountingBook') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##TempAccountingBook

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempAccountingBookReport') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##TempAccountingBookReport

SELECT 
    InvoiceDescriptions.InvoiceID, Invoices.InvcoiceDate, InvoiceSeries, 
    InvoiceNumber, InvoiceApology, TotalAmount, Amount, BookTitle, VatValue
INTO
    ##TempAccountingBook
FROM
    Invoices
JOIN
    InvoiceDescriptions ON InvoiceDescriptions.InvoiceID = Invoices.InvoiceID
JOIN 
    BookTitles ON InvoiceDescriptions.BookTitleID = BookTitles.BookTitleID

DECLARE @SQLQUERY AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @PivotColumns = COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(BookTitle)
FROM [dbo].[BookTitles]

SET @SQLQUERY = N'SELECT [InvoiceID], [InvcoiceDate], [InvoiceSeries], [InvoiceNumber], [InvoiceApology], [TotalAmount],' + @PivotColumns +' , [VatValue]
INTO ##TempAccountingBookReport
FROM ##TempAccountingBook
PIVOT (MAX([Amount])
    FOR [BookTitle] IN (' + @PivotColumns +')) AS Q'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQUERY

SELECT * FROM ##TempAccountingBookReport
```